# In R, scatterplot and smoother are split by factor (colour = factor), but I want the lines to differ by greyscale or linetype, not colour

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, regression

I have a scatterplot with a smoother split by a 2-level factor; I need to keep it all on one graph, but cannot use colour.

So I'd like the two levels of the factor to differ either (1) by grayscale (e.g., dark grey vs. black) (2) or by linetype (e.g., dashed vs. solid).

Thanks,

Data:

```
ppn, condition,pns, apav

1,inconsistenr,3.92,2.00
2,inconsistent,2.50,3.75
3,consistent, 4.08,2.25
4,inconsistent,2.67,5.50
5,consistent,3.58,5.00 (...)
```

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
scatter <- ggplot(PINC3, aes(pns, apav, colour = condition))
scatter + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", alpha = .15)
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRqcb.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set colours to just grey scale using RColorBrewer palettes that are part of ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)
scatter <- ggplot(PINC3, aes(pns, apav, colour = condition))
scatter + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", alpha = .15) +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Greys)
```

To set the linetype depending on `condition` use `linetype` as an aesthetic, and it should work with `geom_smooth`:

```
scatter <- ggplot(PINC3, aes(pns, apav, linetype = condition))
scatter +
    geom_point(aes(shape = condition)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", alpha = .15)
```

Comment: linetype worked like a charm, greyscale was too bright so I increased luminance. but... is there a way to manipulate the scatterplot elements too? the graph looks good now but the scatterplot datapoints look all the same. i wonder whether we can differentiate them too, e.g., with different lines or symbols (e.g., circles vs. triangles). thanks,

Comment: `geom_point(aes(shape = condition))` should give you different shaped point for each condition